# BCP Error SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 , Unable to open BCP host data-file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sysdba

I am trying to execute the below BCP query in my TEST Server, where BCP has a connection string to the production DB, so my destination folder is in my Test Server and I am getting an error, I think it's a permission related issue.

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(2000), @path NVARCHAR(200)='Z:\SQL' , @TableName NVARCHAR(100)='tblUsers' Set @str = 'BCP IDB.dbo.'+@TableName+ ' OUT '+@path +'\'+@TableName+'.csv -c -t^| -T -S ProductionServerName\SQL2012' Exec xp_cmdshell @str

Print (@str) = BCP IDB.dbo.tblUsers OUT Z:\SQL\tblUsers.csv -c -t^| -T -S ProductionServerName\SQL2012
```

> ERROR: output SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error =
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Unable to open BCP host
>   data-file NULL

I shared my Test Server folder to the Production User account. Also I have mapped the shared folder drive as a network share in production and run the below SQL statements:

```
EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'net use Z: \\TestServevrName\Test'

EXEC XP_CMDSHELL 'Dir Z:'
```

Still I am facing the same Issue.

Please guide me what steps are required to fix this permissions issue.

Comment: Specify a UNC path to the file instead of a mapped drive. For example, if your share name is `SQL`, specify `\\TestServer\SQL\tblUsers.csv`.

Comment: I given the same it is not working

Comment: Did you grant the account permissions to both the share and the folders/files within? If the invoking user a member of the sysadmin role on the test server, it is the test server SQL Server service account that needs permissions. For non-sysadmin role members, the xp_cmdshell Proxy account needs permissions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql).